# I try to shorten a string by two characters depending on two parameter I pass into a function. How?

Tags: javascript, string, loops

I have a string, say "Antonello". I want a function that shortens it by two characters (that I pass in as parameter) e.g. 0, 8 should lead to "ntonell".

This is the code I tried:

```
function strCut(str, index, index2) {
debugger;
    var arr = []

    for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
        if(index != i || index2 != i) {
            arr.push(str[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr.join("");
}
```

I assumed that if 0 (passed in) is not equal to the i of the loop it will evaluate true and therefore push the strings index into the array (which I then turn into a string.

However, `strCut('Antonello', 0,8)` results the complete string "Antonello". Why?

Comment: Since we are covering substrings in this chapter, I assume they need to play a role, but I thought I can go without them.

Comment: *"e.g. 0, 8 should lead to "ntonell""* What's the logic there? Why doesn't it have an "A" on it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the tow index that I pass in are positions that should be deducted from the string. Here. the zero-position and eighth-position should be taken away. Therefore "ntonell"

Comment: Use substring() function to reach you goal.

Comment: one of the comparison is always true.

Comment: Thx @NinaScholz Makes sense.

Comment: @Jackkobec How would this look like with substrings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `&&` instead of `||`.

When you use `||` it means that if the `i` is not equal to `index1` **or** not equal to `index2`. This will always evaluate to `true`. Consider `i` is `index1` then `index2 !== i` will `true` and whole expression will become true.

```js
function strCut(str, index, index2) {
    var arr = []

    for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
        if(index !== i && index2 !== i) {
            arr.push(str[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr.join("");
}

console.log(strCut("Antonello", 0, 8))
```

For more that two indexes to remove you can use rest parameters and `filter()`

```js
function strCut(str, ...indexes) {
    indexes = new Set(indexes);
    return [...str].filter((x, i) => !indexes.has(i)).join('');
}

console.log(strCut("Antonello", 0, 8, 1))
```

You can also do it using `substring` but it will be little messy. Also the indexes passed should be in order.

```js
function strCut(str, index, index2) {
    return str.substring(0, index) + str.substring(index + 1, index2) + str.substring(index2 + 1, str.length);
}

console.log(strCut("Antonello", 1, 4))
```

Comment: That's the solution. But why? Isn't it more logical to say that i should not be index NOR index2. Can you walk me through?

Comment: @user2132380 I have added an explanation check it.

Comment: Is this also possible with substring?

Comment: @user2132380 Yes I have added that version. Also a general way for more than two indexes. Personally I won't use `substring`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
const test = 'Antonello';


function strCut(str, index, index2) {
  if (!str) {
    return;
  }

  return str.substring(index + 1, index2);
}

const result = strCut(test, 0 ,8);
```

More simple:

```
function strCut(str, index, index2) {
  return str && str.substring(index + 1, index2);
}
```

> 'ntonell'

Comment: It uses substring() fuction. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: @Jackkobec You may want to explain how the `return` part of it works. If they just started then they may not understand how it's returning the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "Antonello";
console.log( strCut(str, 0, 8) );

function strCut(str, start, end) {
  if ( start > str.length || end > str.length ){ return; }
  
  return str.slice(start + 1, end);
}
```